# Как остановить функцию при прокрутке js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Вот скрипт который работает следующим образом : есть 7 блоков , между ними разстояние 100 px и они все находятся в блоке "timeline".В этом блоке если легонько прокрутить колесико мышки оно автоматически прокрутится к следующему блоку (типа как слайдер).Проблемка  следующая: после блока таймлайн идут еще блоки (продолжение страницы одним словом) и прокрутка должна становится обычной. В коде прописано что если `num > 7 num = 7`.В общем нужно чтобы если num > 7 функция останавливалась и пользователь крутит дальше вниз страницы **НО** ЕСЛИ ОН  НАЧНЕТ КРУТИТЬ ВВЕРХ ПРОКРУТКА В ТАЙМЛАЙНЕ ОПЯТЬ ДОЛЖНА РАБОТАТЬ КАК ИЗНАЧАЛЬНО

```js
var num = 1;
var scrolling = false;

$(".timeline").bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event) {
  scroll(event);
});


function scroll(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (!scrolling) {
    scrolling = true;
    if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0 || event.originalEvent.detail > 0) {
      num++;
       num = num > 7 ? 7 : num;  
    } 
    else {
      num--;
      num = num < 1 ? 1 : num;
    }

   $('html, .timeline').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".num" + num).offset().top -100
  }, 
  500, "linear", function() {
    scrolling = false;
  }); 
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Селектор `<div class="js-animationElement">...</div>`
В зоне видимости добавляется класс inView и убирается. Вот пример

```
    var $animationElement = $('.js-animationElement'),
    $window = $(window);

    function inView() {
        var windowHeight = $window.height(),
            delta = windowHeight * 3 / 4,
            windowWidth = $window.width(),
            windowTop = $window.scrollTop(),
            windowBottom = (windowTop + delta);


        $animationElement.each(function() {
            var $element = $(this),
                elementHeight = $element.outerHeight(),
                elementTop = $element.offset().top,
                elementBottom = (elementTop + elementHeight);

            if (elementBottom >= windowTop && elementTop <= windowBottom) {
                $element.addClass('inView');
            }
        });
    }

    $window.on('scroll resize', inView);
    $window.trigger('scroll');  
    }
```